# A finely open set, not open up to polar set?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Is there a (simple) example of a finely open set (i.e. w.r.t. the fine topology in potential theory) $O$ in $\mathbb R^n$, which is not open up to a polar set (i.e. zero capacity), i.e., there does not exist a polar set $M$, such that the symmetric difference of $O$ and $M$ is open?

I found some examples of finely open sets, but all were "almost" open (in the above sense).

Comment: I'm not familiar with finitely open sets, but they seem similar to radially/algebraically open sets. A nice example of such a set that is very far from being open is to take the complement of a dense subset of the plane that has no three points colinear.

Comment: @TomHutchcroft: Thank you for your comment, but I think you mixed "finitely open" and "finely open".

Comment: Oops, sorry about that

Comment: recently posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128581 with more detail

Comment: Just so I understand what you're saying ... the fine topology is the one that makes subharmonic functions continuous. You are asking if a finely open set (which we can think of as the preimage of some open set by some subharmonic function), can differ from a traditionally open set by a set of capacity other than zero? 

And how is this related to the discontinuity points of a subharmonic function? (pardon any elementary errors. I just looked up what the fine topology was on Wikipedia for this question, and it's the first time I've seen it)

Comment: I am also not familiar with the fine topology. The answer to your first question is 'yes'. The relation to discontinuity points is unclear to me.

Comment: This is not an answer, but might be of some help in resolving the question.

It is known that the fine topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the quasi-Lindelöf property:

"An arbitrary union of fine-open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ differs by a polar set from countable subunion."
(proved in J. L. Doob, 'Classical Potential Theory and its Probabilistic Counterpart' - page 181, in my 1984 Springer edition)

Comment: So, since any fine open set is a union of a collection of sets from a base for the fine topology, we know that it differs by a polar set from a countable union of sets from the base, so that, if we could prove that any such set in the base only differs from a (usual) open set by a polar set, then we would have settled the question (since a countable union of polar sets is itself polar).